# Screen tearing with GT 730M (and no Sync to VBlank option in Nvidia settings)

Tags: unity, 14.04, drivers, intel-graphics, tearing

I've got problems with screen tearing while using Geforce gt 730M (GPU is Optimus with additionally Intel 4000). Tearing appears during scrolling websites, watching movies, playing games etc. I've read on many forums that it should be checked Sync to VBlank option in nvidia x server settings in opengl settings but I don't have such option (there's only "Use Conformant Texture Clamping" which is marked).

Now I'm using nvidia 340.32 drivers from `xorg-edgers/ppa` but the issue was the same with 331.38 drivers from repository. With Linux mint (my first Linux at all) also the same. So far I've tried for example to set Nvidia settings on "prefer maximum performance" or to add to `/etc/environment/` the following:

```
CLUTTER_PAINT=disable-clipped-redraws:di­sable-culling
CLUTTER_VBLANK=True
```

Nothing works. I really need your help and every try is welcomed. If it matters, in windows 7 there was no problem with my GT 730M.

Regards